# Mysql : help ordering a select statement AND getting the middle of the set

Tags: mysql

So I have

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 100;
```

What I would like to do is get a set of 100 based on an ... "index?"  Basically I would like to get say 50th to 149th  or 300th to 399th.

Sorry I just don't know the term for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 100 , 50 ;
```

You need to use offset. Pass 300 instead of 50 and you will get result set from 300 too 400

Edit: This would get 100 -> 400 as the first value is the start index when using ','

Comment: Thank you for direction, Limit startRow, num  or Limit num offset startRow.  Note your description is wrong according to the docs.